# In Slide Menu Control With Tab View Giving Tabs Empty In Android Studio

Tags: android, menu, tabs, fragment, swipe

Actually, I'm working one app that app has side menu drawer and in a home page, tab view is there.

In that menu have 5 fragments let's say

1. HomeFragment
2. PhotosFragment
3. NotificationsFragment

   These are in menu and in home fragment, two tabs are like recent tab and all tab

so now I'm going to say what happened, menu control and tab control working without bug but whenever app starting time only.
I mean see now app started by default it shows home fragment, in that home fragment I said know 2 tabs are there.So those are working but now coming to point what was the bug.

If I select another menu item to let's say Photos Fragment then after again I select Home Fragment those tabs are not showing.
I mean whenever app starts the first time its showing tabs after that not showing.

Why its coming like this really I don't know I checked lot ways.

this is my code

main_activity class

```
      @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mHandler = new Handler();

    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

    // Navigation view header
    navHeader = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    txtName = (TextView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.name);
    txtWebsite = (TextView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.website);
    imgNavHeaderBg = (ImageView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.img_header_bg);
    imgProfile = (ImageView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.img_profile);

    // load toolbar titles from string resources
    activityTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_item_activity_titles);

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    // load nav menu header data
    loadNavHeader();

    // initializing navigation menu
    setUpNavigationView();

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        navItemIndex = 0;
        CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;
        loadHomeFragment();
    }
}

/***
 * Load navigation menu header information
 * like background image, profile image
 * name, website, notifications action view (dot)
 */
private void loadNavHeader() {
    // name, website
    txtName.setText("Dummy");
    txtWebsite.setText("www.dumnypaul.blogspot.in");

    // loading header background image
    Glide.with(this).load(urlNavHeaderBg)
            .crossFade()
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .into(imgNavHeaderBg);

    // Loading profile image
    Glide.with(this).load(urlProfileImg)
            .crossFade()
            .thumbnail(0.5f)
            .bitmapTransform(new CircleTransform(this))
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .into(imgProfile);

    // showing dot next to notifications label
    navigationView.getMenu().getItem(3).setActionView(R.layout.menu_dot);
}

/***
 * Returns respected fragment that user
 * selected from navigation menu
 */
private void loadHomeFragment() {
    // selecting appropriate nav menu item
    selectNavMenu();

    // set toolbar title
    setToolbarTitle();

    // if user select the current navigation menu again, don't do anything
    // just close the navigation drawer
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(CURRENT_TAG) != null) {
        drawer.closeDrawers();

        // show or hide the fab button
        toggleFab();
        return;
    }

    // Sometimes, when fragment has huge data, screen seems hanging
    // when switching between navigation menus
    // So using runnable, the fragment is loaded with cross fade effect
    // This effect can be seen in Gmail app
    Runnable mPendingRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // update the main content by replacing fragments
            Fragment fragment = getHomeFragment();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in,
                    android.R.anim.fade_out);
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment, CURRENT_TAG);
            fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
        }
    };

    // If mPendingRunnable is not null, then add to the message queue
    if (mPendingRunnable != null) {
        mHandler.post(mPendingRunnable);
    }

    // show or hide the fab button
    toggleFab();

    //Closing drawer on item click
    drawer.closeDrawers();

    // refresh toolbar menu
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}

private Fragment getHomeFragment() {
    switch (navItemIndex) {
        case 0:
            // home
            HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
            return homeFragment;
        case 1:
            // photos
            PhotosFragment photosFragment = new PhotosFragment();
            return photosFragment;
        case 2:
            // movies fragment
            MoviesFragment moviesFragment = new MoviesFragment();
            return moviesFragment;
        case 3:
            // notifications fragment
            NotificationsFragment notificationsFragment = new NotificationsFragment();
            return notificationsFragment;

        case 4:
            // settings fragment
            SettingsFragment settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();
            return settingsFragment;
        default:
            return new HomeFragment();
    }
}

private void setToolbarTitle() {
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(activityTitles[navItemIndex]);
}

private void selectNavMenu() {
    navigationView.getMenu().getItem(navItemIndex).setChecked(true);
}

private void setUpNavigationView() {
    //Setting Navigation View Item Selected Listener to handle the item click of the navigation menu
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        // This method will trigger on item Click of navigation menu
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

            //Check to see which item was being clicked and perform appropriate action
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                //Replacing the main content with ContentFragment Which is our Inbox View;
                case R.id.home:
                    navItemIndex = 0;
                    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_photos:
                    navItemIndex = 1;
                    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_PHOTOS;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_movies:
                    navItemIndex = 2;
                    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_MOVIES;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_notifications:
                    navItemIndex = 3;
                    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_NOTIFICATIONS;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_settings:
                    navItemIndex = 4;
                    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_SETTINGS;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_about_us:
                    // launch new intent instead of loading fragment
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AboutUsActivity.class));
                    drawer.closeDrawers();
                    return true;
                case R.id.nav_privacy_policy:
                    // launch new intent instead of loading fragment
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, PrivacyPolicyActivity.class));
                    drawer.closeDrawers();
                    return true;
                default:
                    navItemIndex = 0;
            }

            //Checking if the item is in checked state or not, if not make it in checked state
            if (menuItem.isChecked()) {
                menuItem.setChecked(false);
            } else {
                menuItem.setChecked(true);
            }
            menuItem.setChecked(true);

            loadHomeFragment();

            return true;
        }
    });


    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.openDrawer, R.string.closeDrawer) {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            // Code here will be triggered once the drawer closes as we don't want anything to happen so we leave this blank
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            // Code here will be triggered once the drawer open as we don't want anything to happen so we leave this blank
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }
    };

    //Setting the actionbarToggle to drawer layout
    drawer.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

    //calling sync state is necessary or else your hamburger icon wont show up
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawers();
        return;
    }

    // This code loads home fragment when back key is pressed
    // when user is in other fragment than home
    if (shouldLoadHomeFragOnBackPress) {
        // checking if user is on other navigation menu
        // rather than home
        if (navItemIndex != 0) {
            navItemIndex = 0;
            CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;
            loadHomeFragment();
            return;
        }
    }

    super.onBackPressed();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

    // show menu only when home fragment is selected
    if (navItemIndex == 0) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    }

    // when fragment is notifications, load the menu created for notifications
    if (navItemIndex == 3) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.notifications, menu);
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //no inspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_logout) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logout user!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }

    // user is in notifications fragment
    // and selected 'Mark all as Read'
    if (id == R.id.action_mark_all_read) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "All notifications marked as read!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    // user is in notifications fragment
    // and selected 'Clear All'
    if (id == R.id.action_clear_notifications) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clear all notifications!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

// show or hide the fab
private void toggleFab() {
    if (navItemIndex == 0)
        fab.show();
    else
        fab.hide();
}
```

}

My HomeFragment Code

```
   public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

View view;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;

public HomeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
     view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);


    tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    return view;
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new MoviesFragment(), "ONE");
    adapter.addFragment(new PhotosFragment(), "TWO");
    adapter.addFragment(new SettingsFragment(), "THREE");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}




class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

}
```

}

My Home Fragment XML Code

```
   <FrameLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   >

   <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabGravity="fill"/>

     <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
     android:id="@+id/viewpager"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

Can anybody solve me this bug

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think your data is dynamic.if it's true then U need to refresh your activity/fragment every time when U comes on Activity/fragment.

Comment: how can i do can you give some instructions @Neo

Comment: according to my code can you say @Neo

Comment: I'm unable to see any data fetching process here. @Santhosh

Comment: Share your project or share that link form where U use this code.

Comment: Or be specific, because  your current code is too hazy.@Santhosh

Comment: HomeFragment class i pasted in that class have two fragments using tab view and those two fragements right now empty not there anything
in future i will update those fragment data
so what i need exact is why tabs are invisible when i come to home second time is there any solution to achieve visible tabs

Comment: There is a quick solution is that U can reload main Activity or refresh your fragment. @Santhosh

Comment: thats why i'm confusing i tried to refresh but i failed my be my code was wrong for refereshing @Neo

Comment: i used this code in case 0 above mentioned code

 finish();
                startActivity(getIntent());

always refereshing like blinking

Comment: because you are reloading activity. So it is blinking @Santhosh

Comment: then how can i bro @Neo please say

Comment: you need a function from where your data comes . and this function will call every time as per your requirement.